# Overwritten all users node. A specific node of all Users on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, click, points

I need help. I am trying to update or rewritten a specific child of every users on Firebase Database. Supposing my database is like this:

Firebase
   |
   --- Users
         |
         --- userId
               |
               --- points
                     |
                     --- 100
I need to update the points of every user and not only the current user but of all the users points when a button is clicked. I tried to figure it out but I could not. Please help me because I don't know how to update the points of all users only the current users.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the list of all user IDs. You can do something like this

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Users");
for (String userID : userIDs) {
    reference.child(userID).child("points").setValue(100); //Points to be updated
}
```

Comment: The code only updates the points of the current user. How do I get all the users and update? I mean, your code is fine, but I did not understand how it will upload all users points cause I don't know how to retrieve all of them to update.

Comment: Can you be more clear? If you have the list of all users in an array or something, you can iterate over the list as I did. Can you post your code?